# sharepoint infopath using icomparer - icomparer fires various times

Tags: infopath

I need to sort repeating items in an infopath form, for that I use an Icomparer with a xpathNavigator and it works if it is used out of the event receivers, when I try to use it in an event receiver the Icomparer function fires various times and it doesn't order the xml either. I have revised that the problem is not event firing various times, the event receiver is fired only once but the comparation is done various times.

```
  public Boolean orderConsequencesByRiskLevelActual(SPWeb web, int riskRegisterId)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlNodeList nodes = null;
                SPList myList = web.Lists[SERVICES.Helpers.Common.Lists.xxxxxxxx];
                SPListItem item = myList.GetItemById(riskRegisterId);
                string newXml = "";
                if (item != null)
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlItem = new XmlDocument();

                    //Open XML file and load it into XML document
                    using (Stream streamItem = item.File.OpenBinaryStream())
                    {
                        xmlItem.Load(streamItem);
                    }


                    // if we got more than a consequence
                    nodes = xmlItem.GetElementsByTagName("my:consequenceItem");
                    if (nodes.Count >=2)
                    {

                        XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlItem.NameTable);
                        nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-06-28T11:33:30");

                        XPathNavigator navigator = xmlItem.CreateNavigator();
                        XPathExpression expression = navigator.Compile("/my:myFields/my:consequencesGroup/my:consequenceItem");
                        // +  expression.AddSort("my:Consequence", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.UpperFirst, string.Empty, XmlDataType.Text);

                        XPathExpression sortExpr = navigator.Compile("my:RiskLevel_actual");
                        sortExpr.SetContext(nameSpaceManager);
                        expression.AddSort(sortExpr, new ConsequenceComparer());

                        expression.SetContext(nameSpaceManager);
                        XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select(expression);
                        foreach (XPathNavigator itemn in iterator)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(itemn.Value);
                            newXml += itemn.OuterXml;
                        }

                        nodes = xmlItem.GetElementsByTagName("my:consequencesGroup");
                        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                        {
                            // node.InnerText += sf.cadena(listaDeRisks[0].Consequences);
                            node.InnerXml = newXml;
                        }

                    }



                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    //Save the modified xml into the item
                    byte[] xmlData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlItem.OuterXml);
                    item.File.SaveBinary(xmlData);
                    item.File.Update();

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //  Logger.Debug("error: riskRegisterServices.update" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public class ConsequenceComparer : IComparer
        {
            public int Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                try
                {
                    string st1 = x.ToString();
                    string st2 = y.ToString();

                    if (st1.Equals(st2))
                        return 0;

                    switch (st1)
                    {
                        case "5A":
                            return 1;
                            break;
                        case "5B":
                        case "4A":
                            switch (st2)
                            {
                                case "5A":
                                    return 1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "5C":
                        case "4B":
                        case "3A":
                            switch (st2)
                            {
                                case "5A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5B":
                                case "4A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "1A":
                        case "2A":
                        case "2B":
                        case "3B":
                        case "3C":
                        case "4C":
                        case "4D":
                        case "5D":
                        case "5E":
                            switch (st2)
                            {
                                case "5A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5B":
                                case "4A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5C":
                                case "4B":
                                case "3A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "1B":
                        case "1C":
                        case "2C":
                        case "2D":
                        case "3D":
                        case "3E":
                        case "4E":
                            switch (st2)
                            {
                                case "5A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5B":
                                case "4A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5C":
                                case "4B":
                                case "3A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "1A":
                                case "2A":
                                case "2B":
                                case "3B":
                                case "3C":
                                case "4C":
                                case "4D":
                                case "5D":
                                case "5E":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "1D":
                        case "1E":
                        case "2E":
                            switch (st2)
                            {
                                case "5A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5B":
                                case "4A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "5C":
                                case "4B":
                                case "3A":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "1A":
                                case "2A":
                                case "2B":
                                case "3B":
                                case "3C":
                                case "4C":
                                case "4D":
                                case "5D":
                                case "5E":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                case "1B":
                                case "1C":
                                case "2C":
                                case "2D":
                                case "3D":
                                case "3E":
                                case "4E":
                                    return  1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            return 0;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }

                return 0;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hi Aron, I posted my code.